# Performance of Xamarin vs. NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

all.

So, I'm completely new to programming, especially mobile development. Considering goals for a future app I'm designing, I've been thinking of using NativeScript. I was reading the book "The NativeScript Book" offered on NativeScript.org, and they were discussiong JIT vs pre-compiling (AOT I guess it is? Correct me if I'm wrong on that). They also showed how a framework like Xamarin compiles down to the native file (.apk for Android and .ipa for Apple) where NativeScript runs in a javascript virtual machine.

When reading this, it seems like code that has been compiled BEFORE and not just at the time of execution would have a significant advantage in terms of speed, especially on phones where they aren't nearly as capable as modern desktop computers.

Can someone address this concern for me? Likely it's because I am ignorant and don't understand things yet, so please enlighten me and help me learn.

THanks :)

Comment: The first thing is: Does it really matter? Unless you run into actual performance issues these questions tend to be over-thinking it

Comment: In my opinion, yes it does matter. Better to ask the question now spend a bunch of time in development, then find out there are performance issues because of the platform I used, then have to write the code again with Xamarin or something else like I may have had to do in the first place.Seems silly to begin development on something without knowing what you're getting into.

Comment: A discussion about the performance difference between AOT and JIT compiled languages/frameworks is too broad for SO (not to mention filled with lots of pitfalls and caveats. Benchmarking is difficult and easy to do wrong). There is no simple answer to this question, if you are worried that NativeScript is not performant enough for your application then use whichever one you think is going to provide you better performance

Comment: Whichever framework / toolkit you choose, the performance also depends on your coding skills too. It's always a never ending debut if you being to think which one is best, and in my opinion the best depends on many factors. For instance if you are a JavaScript developer then NativeScript suits you very well. If you are from C#, learning JavaScript tech stack may be difficult for you, so choosing Xamarin would be wise choice. There is even Flutter from Google if you are good with Dart.

Comment: FYI, any frameworks including Xamarin, NativeScript or even Flutter produces an APK (Android) / IPA (iOS) at the end because that is what the operating system can understand. There is no great difference between Xamarin and NativeScript. Both provide unlimited access to native apis, both have their run times.

Comment: It is nice idea to be thinking about performance, but you are doing it a bit early, at this stage focus on actually making something without getting too distracted by these details.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to programming, the performance of the framework should not be one of your priorities. You should start by focusing on other aspects, like portability, or simplicity of the solution. Learning to write good software should be your top priority instead of trying to write fast software.

Nonetheless, if this is really important for you, there are some benchmarks available opposing the different mobile oriented frameworks. For instance, the NativeScript website has one :

https://www.nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-and-xamarin

Check the 'Speed' section. It states for instance :

**In these tests, you can see that Xamarin is roughly 200 ms faster than NativeScript at startup time.**

But as you'll notice that when comparing performances, benchmarks always target only one aspect of the solution. This one in particular targets boot time. Some others target sorting of large arrays, or HTTP requests speed.

It is impossible to get a global performance test indicating which solution is the best. I think that one good example in that regard is the comparison of Xamarin VS Native languages (Swift // Java). Check this page :

https://www.altexsoft.com/blog/engineering/performance-comparison-xamarin-forms-xamarin-ios-xamarin-android-vs-android-and-ios-native-applications/

Xamarin is close to native solutions since it uses the native SDKs, but you will notice big differences between Xamarin and native. So it would be event more complicated to compare Xamarin and NativeScript which has a completely different logic !

In my opinion, you should start by the framework you like the most. And change it based on your experiences if you are not satisfied with it.